# HTML 5 draggable attribute question

Tags: html

Does the HTML 5 draggable attribute have a value auto if so can I place it in an element like in the following example. `<p draggable="auto">...</p>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTML 5 Standard Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp)

This attribute is in the list of supported by all HTML 5 tags. So, apparently, you can.

Comment: Your linked page is gone - 404

Answer (score 2):

The default *state* of the [`draggable`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html#the-draggable-attribute) attribute is “auto”, but it must not be specified in markup. An HTML5 validator reports `draggable="auto"` as an error.

To make the `draggable` attribute state “auto”, simply do not specify the attribute in markup at all. This is part of the confusing [“enumerated attributes”](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#keywords-and-enumerated-attributes) concept in HTML5.